# How to import by drag n drop web files from browser to an electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, drag-and-drop, electron

I'm building an electron app.
One of my features is to drag and drop any files to store them into the electron & vue app.

It works well with local files stored on my computer.  I can't do the same with files from a web browser (till now I've tried in Chrome).

I use the `dragover` and `ondrop` events to check the file's data.  With files from browser I don't have any data in those events.

```
export default {
 name: 'colors',
 mounted () {
   document.ondragover = document.ondrop = (ev) => {
     ev.preventDefault()
     // console.log(ev)
   }

   document.body.ondrop = (ev) => {
     console.log(ev)
     ev.preventDefault()
   }
 }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I think an exempale of the electron app is in order.

Comment: I just updated with the code example

Answer (score 1):

The starting point you're looking for is `event.dataTransfer.getData('url')`.

When you drag an image from the browser into your Electron app, the "data" you're handed is a URL string pointing to the image. It's accessed by calling the `getData()` method, and passing in **"url"** as the DOMString.

So with your example, to get the url to the image you just dragged in, you'd do

```
document.body.ondrop = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const imageUrl = ev.dataTransfer.getData('url');
    // will set imageUrl equal to something like "https://somewebsite.com/your-image.jpg"
}
```

[This MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData) explains working with dataTransfer's `getData()` in a bit more detail, but they don't mention exactly which arguments you can pass to `getData()`. If you dig into the [W3C spec for HTML5 Drag and Drop](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/dnd.html#the-datatransfer-interface), you'll see that it accepts a string of either **"text"** or **"url"**. You'd use **"text"** if you were dragging and dropping a link or text block into your app, and **"url"** for images.

According to the W3C spec:

> If format equals "text", change it to "text/plain".
>
> If format equals "url", change it to "text/uri-list" and set
>   convert-to-URL to true.

---

So what do you do once you have that URL? Well, you would need to download the image by streaming it to a file, and that will give you the actual image file on your computer to be moved/renamed/whatever by your app. Assuming you're using a library like [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request):

```
function downloadImage(imageUrl) {
    request({ url: imageUrl, encoding: null }, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      const destination = 'some/app/folder/image.jpg;
      fs.createWriteStream(destination).write(body);
    });
  }
```